# Visual Studio 2010 Unit test allways gives NullReferenceException error

Tags: unit-testing, c#-2.0

I am trying make Unit test with Unit test wizard, but I am always getting:

> Test method TestProject9.Log_InsertMasterTest threw exception:
>   System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

My test.cs:

```
    [TestMethod()]
    [DeploymentItem("Engine.dll")]
    public void Log_InsertMasterTest()
    {
        SkinnedRepairSearch_Accessor target = new SkinnedRepairSearch_Accessor(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        int RepairMasterID = 0; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        int RepairMasterIDOld = 0; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        int id = 0; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        string Text = string.Empty; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
        target.Log_InsertMaster(RepairMasterID, RepairMasterIDOld, id, Text);
        Assert.Inconclusive("A method that does not return a value cannot be verified.");
    }
```

Log_InsertMaster method:

```
protected void Log_InsertMaster(int RepairMasterID, int RepairMasterIDOld, int id, string Text)
{
    SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(Globals.DatabaseConnectionString);

    SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand("dbo.Repair_LogInsertMaster", myConnection);
    myCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@RepairMasterID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = RepairMasterID;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@RepairMasterIDold", SqlDbType.Int).Value = RepairMasterIDOld;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@DateTime", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = System.DateTime.Now;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@RepairID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@UserSignature", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = AdminUser.Signature;
    myCommand.Parameters.Add("@Text", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 200).Value = Text;

    myConnection.Open();
    myCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    myConnection.Close();
}
```

How to not get this error? And how to use Unint testing wizard?

Exception line:

```
SkinnedRepairSearch_Accessor target = new SkinnedRepairSearch_Accessor(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
```

I tried and other, public method:

```
[TestMethod()]
public void EmptyTextBoxesTest()
{
    SkinnedRepair target = new SkinnedRepair(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
    Control parent = null; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
    target.EmptyTextBoxes(parent);
    Assert.Inconclusive("A method that does not return a value cannot be verified.");
}
```

same error

Comment: *Where* is the exception thrown, exactly?

Comment: Can you tell us which exact line of code in your test raises the exception please?

Comment: SkinnedRepairSearch_Accessor target = new SkinnedRepairSearch_Accessor(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value

Comment: Try deleting the private accessor class file for you test and rebuild it. You can do that by right-clicking inside the SkinnedRepairSearch class and choose 'Create Private Accessor'. Other then that, I can't see what else could be causing an exception on that line.

Comment: Chances are that's not the line that is actually throwing the exception- it's likely somewhere *within* the constructor of the SkinnedRepairSearch_Accessor class.